# Prove that if $1+ab\equiv 0[24]$ then $a+b\equiv 0[24]$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$.
**Prove that if $1+ab\equiv  0[24]$ then $a+b\equiv  0[24]$**
My attempts: 
$1+ab\equiv  0[24]\implies ab\equiv -1[24]$
so : $ab\equiv 23[24]$
Then there $k\in\mathbb {N}$ such as $ab=24k$ 
But how can I move to $a+b$?.

Comment: Having arrived at the fact that $ab\equiv 23\mod(24)$, your next question should be: what are the factors of $23$ modulo $24$? List them in pairs, then add them modulo $24$. What do you get?